# What might be the reason for the Image not occupying the full screen in the 10.1 galaxy tablet while running my android application?

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

I have created an android application and its running fine on my emulator.But the problem really is whenever I want to run it on a Samsung Galaxy 10.1 tab,the application screen appears to be tiny.Could somebody help me out in this regard and tell me how to make my application acquire the whole of the screen in the tab? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you want to read this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html<br>
If someone links to a pre existing SO question pointing to that guide please accept their answer not mine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I think, that you need to read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) You need to make your application, to be "big" on the tablets too. I think that it will be "very important" until 3.2 .

Be happy with Galaxy Tab 10.1 :)